# Regular expression - ignore first 7 character from extracted data

Tags: regex

Extracting data from a page source. In the extracted data, need to display text after the ". Tried different options. Didn't work. Any suggestions
Page source text 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqDhZ.jpg)

input type name=loginForm_SUBMIT value="1" /input type=""name="faces.ViewState" id="faces.ViewState" value="9uiY/UWJ1/w3PQ==" /><

regular expression: value="[^"1" ].*\w==
Output: value="9uiY/UWJ1/w3PQ==
Expected Output: 9uiY/UWJ1/w3PQ==

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Can your language use capture groups? F.e. `value="([A-Za-z0-9\/]*==)"` then get capture group $1. And btw, for what language or regex engine is this? F.e. in the PCRE regex engine you can use \K, but not in the simple regex engine used in javascript.

Comment: If you insist to keep your version, thanks to use code blocks `{}` for code and did you see my full featured answer ?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: Thx Gilles, Niceal and LukStorms. Links and recommendations were helpful

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query.

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

#### Example using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//input[@value][2]/@value)' file
```

### Output :

```
9uiY/UWJ1/w3PQ==
```

Comment: Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter does not support xpath. I am testing this in https://regexr.com/. xpath not supported there as well

Comment: Feel free to use a bazooka to kill a fly. You never add JMeter flag anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
(?:value[^v]*value=\")([^\"]*)
```

The output you want is captured in group 1, and you can retrieve it by backreference \1 or $1.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/33)

"value=" is occurred twice in your sample text, so you seemed use the regex(value="[^"1" ].*\w==) to avoid the first one and match second one.

But the regex is wrong because character class'[...]' means one character. If the character class is followed by the quantifier(repeater) *, +, or {min,max} etc, then it's possible the regex means the string which has multiple characters.

Comment: Thx Thm. Recommendation worked with a little tweek. Its working and grabbing the exact text.